# Laravel dates extensively in Portuguese

Tags: laravel, date, ubuntu, locale, php-carbon

I am trying to show dates in Portuguese using Laravel & Carbon

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF-8');
$dt = Carbon::today();
Carbon::setToStringFormat('jS \o\f F, Y g:i:s a');
echo $dt
echo $dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')
```

but it seams Locate is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't include all locales by default.

You can verify using the command locale:

```
$ locale -a

POSIX
C.UTF-8
C
en_**.UTF-8
```

To install Portuguese, use the command

```
sudo locale-gen pt_BR
```

I hope it helps you.